# Linking characters in a form to specific attributes in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am new to programming, understand the basics, but have a specific question for the experts.

I am trying to link the individual characters of a string entered into an html form to particular images in a mysql database. For example, a user might type T-H-E and the output would be three independent images drawn to correspond to those three characters.

I understand how to make the MYSQL database (with tags as attributes corresponding to characters) and how to make an html form to submit the word itself, but how do I connect it together?

I assume it is a php script, but not sure which one?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you actually running php on your server?  What do you plan to do if an image for a particular character is not found?

Comment: Thanks. I am running php. All the images aren't up yet, but presumably there would be an image for each character. I guess I'm not sure how to break apart the characters that would come in as a string--"honey"--into independent variables (i.e. five variables h-o-n-e-y) that I can match with attribute fields in the mysql database...Any thoughts or help with how to code deeply appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$letters = str_split($_REQUEST['letters']);

array_walk($letters, 'mysql_real_escape_string');
$letters = "'" . implode("','", $letters) . "'";
$query = "SELECT images FROM Image WHERE letter IN ($letters)";
```

Comment: Thanks! That really helped me along. Now I'm just having trouble figuring out how to constrain the output so that only one random image per letter (among many tagged with "h" for example) is returned and in the same order as the original input from the form. But that may be a a question for a different forum...

Comment: @user1015580 you can always ask another question